# Cocoa Touch method from another class gets called but the code doesn't run

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

So, I realize this is very similar to dozens of other questions out there, so let me assure you that I've read them, understand MVC, have read books, etc.... but I'm still stumped.

I have two classes... A and B. A calls B as a Modal Segue. B has a 'cancel' button that dismisses itself and returns to A. I want to call a method (or set a property) on A when this happens.

I have imported A into B and made an iVar of it (also tried a property), allocated it in ViewDidLoad, then am attempting various ways of either setting a property or calling a method on A from a method (IBAction or prepareForSegue) of B.

Properties seem to have no effect... Nothing visibly changes, and they log as unchanged.
I can get a NSLog of my method to fire - which is an encouraging sanity check, but none of the other code in the method fires...

Here's my current version:

Class A:

has an ImageView that is hidden on VDL.
I am either trying to make it unhidden - or failing that, to never create it until my method gets called....

```
- (void) makeGoalVisible {
    NSLog(@"GOAL"); // this prints

    UIImageView *goal = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(906, 442, 61, 93)];
    goal.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goalIndicator@2x.png"];

    [self.view addSubview:goal]; // this method works from WITHIN Class A - so I know the code/position is fine

}
```

Class B:

```
- (IBAction)pressedCancel:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"CANCEL");

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"setGoal" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"PREP");

    TimelineViewController *host = [[TimelineViewController alloc]init];

    [host makeGoalVisible]; // this calls the method but the method doesnt work
    //[host.goalIndicator setHidden:NO]; // this doesnt work
}
```

All the logs from the methods print in the expected order... and like I said, the method is getting called from Class B, and the code in the method gets called if I call it from Class A but not Class B...

What am I missing ???

Comment: What are you trying to hide/show?

Comment: It is a UIImageView...

Comment: If it is **UIImageView *goal**, I didn't see any property `setHidden:` anywhere. Moreover, you have made your `UIImageView` instance is local

Comment: Well, "goalIndicator" is a UIImageView property that is declared and synthesized in Class A... originally I was trying to access the setter  (setHidden, which you can see I'm trying to call in the Class B method), but it didn't work, so I was trying to never create/hide it at all until the method of Class A was called from Class B instead... So *goal is a completely local version to the called method, yes... Sorry, the example code I posted had a bit of a mix of different strategies I had tried...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code as you called this `UIViewController` using `segue` so you can get the object using `[segue destinationViewController];` as there is no need to create an new obejct using `TimelineViewController *host = [[TimelineViewController alloc]init];`

so this the reason your code printing `NSLog(@"GOAL");` but called from separate object

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"PREP");
    TimelineViewController *host = [segue destinationViewController];
    [host makeGoalVisible]; 
    //[host.goalIndicator setHidden:NO]; 
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, it works! Thank you... (will accept as soon as SO lets me)... but I'm curious, what if I wanted to call the method from an IBAction and didn't have the reference to the destinationViewController ??

Comment: if you want to call this function you need to initialise the `UIViewController` class as you using `segue` and it creating an object (as you getting the reference using `[segue destinationViewController];`) both are different.

Comment: if you move on `UIViewController` using code (without `segue`) then you code will work because that time the object you create will move as `nextViewController`. Hope this will help You :)

Answer (score 1):

Your basic premise is wrong. If you use a modal push from A to be, you either need to call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: explicitly, or use an unwind segue.

If you are using `performSegueWithIdentifier:` to get from B to A then you are creating a new copy of A, not returning to the original instance of A. You are creating an ever-increasing stack of modal view controllers, which is wrong.

The normal technique for communicating from B back to A is to set up A as a delegate of B in A's prepareForSegue. Then, in B, you use the delegate to make a call/set a property in A.

Comment: I actually know this - though am a little shaky on my understanding of delegates still - but this is a prototype app that I am helping some of my students with, and I'm faking a master-detail view... complicated scenario, but I'm cheating on my navigation for various reasons...

Comment: Ok, but invoking a new segue as a way of "getting back" to the previous view controller is W-R-O-N-G WRONG. No two ways about it, it will not work as intended.